# How can I display a dynamic list of saved items in my application

Tags: django

I am trying to get Django to show the List of saved inputs from the user on the index page.
( I know my frankenstein-ed code is horrible, it has a lot of tiny bits of things I tried out and didn't get to work. I don't have much programming experience, I'm just trying to get this done for a graded project at my uni. )

The whole project should be a prototype for a food storage application, the user puts the food in via dropdown menu (I will expand it with subcategories e.g. Milk based food => cheese) and should be able to view what is in storage and be able to remove items. Right now I am getting stuck on making the list viewable by the user. Any help is much appreciated!

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

 

class FoodCategory(models.Model):
    MILK = 'MLK'
    VEGETABLE = 'VG'
    MEAT = 'MT'
    PASTA = 'PST'
    FRUIT = 'GR'
    FOOD_CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        (MILK, 'Milk based foods'),
        (VEGETABLE, 'Vegetables'),
        (MEAT, 'Meats'),
        (PASTA, 'Pasta'),
        (FRUIT, 'Fruits'),
    ]
    foodcategory = models.TextField(
        choices= FOOD_CATEGORY_CHOICES,
        default= MILK,
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'foodcategory'
        verbose_name_plural = 'food_list'   
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.foodcategory
```

View.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = FoodCategory
    template_name = 'foodstorage/index.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return FoodCategory.objects.all()

def WorkView(request):
    form = SelectionForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SelectionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            foodlist = form.save(commit = False)
            foodlist.save()
            #cd = form.cleaned_data
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('foodstorage:index'))


    else:
        form = SelectionForm()


    return render(request, 
                  'foodstorage/work.html', 
                  {'form': form})

def overview(request):
    all_food =  FoodCategory.objects.all()
    context = {
    "all_food" : all_food
    }
    return render(request, 'foodstorage/index.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


app_name = 'foodstorage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('work/', views.WorkView, name='work'),
]
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

{% block content %}
<h1>food storage home</h1>

<ul>

    <h1>List of food:</h1>
    {% for foodcategory in all_food %}
      <h1>{{all_food}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

    
  <a href="{% url 'foodstorage:work' %}">Enter new food</a>
</ul>


{% endblock %}
```

Please let me know if more code is needed to solve this issue.

EDIT

Forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import FoodCategory


class SelectionForm (ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = FoodCategory
        fields = ['foodcategory']
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of `SelectionForm` (should be in `forms.py`)?

Comment: Sure, did that just now!

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
 <h1>List of food:</h1>
    {% for foodcat in all_food %}
      <li>{{ foodcat }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt show any list on the page